# OpenOffice.org 3.3 exception prevents startup

Tags: windows-7, boot, openoffice

Since upgrading to OpenOffice 3.3 on 64-bit Windows 7, OpenOffice.org fails to start and displays the following error:

> The application cannot be started.
>
> [context="user"] caught unexpected exception!

Worked fine at version 3.2.

What's going on, and what's the workaround, if any?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this from [here](http://www.syahzul.com/tutorial/2011/05/the-application-cannot-be-started-context-user-caught-unexpected-exception/):

> Windows 7
>
> 1. Show hidden files/folders: By default, our AppData folder is hidden, so we need to show all hidden files and folders before we start.
> 2. Open your AppData folder
>      Open your AppData folder, in my case `C:\Users\syahzul\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice\3`.
> 3. Delete LibreOffice Profile: Delete or move all the contents to other place.
> 4. Start LibreOffice
>      Once you start the application, LibreOffice will find the profile folder, if not exists it will re-create one for you.
>
> After few days struggling with the issue it [now works]. I hope it works for you too.

It's for LibreOffice, but you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered a failing SSD and, in restoring the contents of the appdata folder on Windows 7, came to suffer the same problem with OO3.4.1.  I followed your suggestion and renamed the OpenOffice.org to OpenOffice.org.failed_to_start.  I then doubleclicked the "OpenOffice.org 3.4.1" shortcut to start the application which had it recreate the OpenOffice.org directory structure.  A little heart failure because it then aborted again, but a second doubleclick started it with success and it runs like a cute puppy.  Ah, computer failures, don't ya love em, show you corners of the universe that you had no desire to ever explore!